# Prove that there is no function $m: \mathbb R^3 \times \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ so that the following conditions apply

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-fields

Could you help me with this task in linear-algebra? I do not know what to do to solve this math problem.I should prove that there is no function $m: \mathbb R^3 \times \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ so that the following conditions apply:

- $m((a,0,0),(b,0,0)) = (ab,0,0) \forall a,b\in \mathbb R$
- $m(av,w) = am(v,w) = m(v,aw) \forall v,w \in \mathbb R^3$ $a \in \mathbb R$
- $\mathbb R^3$ is a field in terms of vector addition and multiplication $m$

I would appreciate it, if you would explain to me the solution in detail or give me a hint, because I want to try to understand the task. I tried my best to translate the task from German into English.

Comment: Hint to start: $m$ must be bilinear, and $(1,0,0)$ will be the multiplicative identity.

Comment: What vector multiplication are you using?  Are you trying to find a multiplication that extends the first line to all vectors?

Comment: @RossMillikan yes

Comment: Since $\mathbb{R}$ embedds to your new field via $x\mapsto (x,0,0)$ we obtain that $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a field extension of $\mathbb{R}$ of degree $3$. And it is well known that $\mathbb{C}$ is the only finite field extension of $\mathbb{R}$. And it is of degree $2$ hence it cannot be your new field. You don't even need the second property. I'm not sure if this is the kind of argumentation you were looking for.